# Errors running unit tests with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

This is what i get from the logs. Please advice on what to do. Thanks.
I've tried uninstalling and installing phantomjs, cleaning my node modules and bower component folders.
It was all working before, and this was all over sudden. Not sure what i did to break things.

```
 PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
      TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.
      at /home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:17


    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
      ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular
      at /home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/src/app/administrator/administrator.module.js:9


    Missing error handler on `socket`.
    TypeError: Cannot read property '83501663' of null
        at onBrowserComplete (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma-junit-reporter/index.js:102:23)
        at null.<anonymous> (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:13:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
        at emit (events.js:172:7)
        at onComplete (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:142:13)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:13:22)
        at emitTwo (events.js:92:20)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:172:7)
        at Socket.onevent (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
        at Socket.onpacket (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
        at Client.ondecoded (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
        at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
        at Decoder.add (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
        at Client.ondata (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    [11:29:04] 'test:unit' errored after 1.56 s
    [11:29:04] Error: 1
        at formatError (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:169:10)
        at Gulp.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:195:15)
        at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
        at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
        at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:264:8)
        at /home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:275:23
        at finish (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:21:8)
        at cb (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:29:3)
        at removeAllListeners (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:336:7)
        at Server.<anonymous> (/home/efremfi/genesis/frontend/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:347:9)
        at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
        at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
        at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
        at emitCloseNT (net.js:1519:8)
        at nextTickCallbackWith1Arg (node.js:431:9)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:353:17)
```

Comment: Managed to solve this. My build folder wasnt available for my test to use the angular object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help? Something about loading **angular** first before **angular mocks**. Have you checked your dependencies?

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13956

Comment: Hey, i already solved this, and added a follow up comment to the question. thank you!